# Orthographische Konsistenz in Anglizismen

Tags: spelling, anglicism

*Fremdwörter* werden in ihrer Grundform üblicherweise unverändert ins Deutsche übernommen. Ihre Schreibung verharrt dann meist statisch für Jahrzehnte oder Jahrhunderte, bevor sie zu *Lehnwörtern* mit eingedeutschter Schreibung werden.
(Die Rechtschreibreform 1996 hat diesbezüglich eher wenig geändert und vieles davon wurde bis 2006 zurückgenommen.)
Bei *flektierten Formen*  hingegen (bspw. beim Plural) erlaubt sich die Sprachgemeinschaft mehr Freiheiten mit ihren Importen und zwingt sie, sich soweit möglich ins vorhandene Sprachsystem einzufügen – oder es werden zumindest germanisierte Varianten akzeptiert (bspw. *s*-Plural nach Vokalauslaut). Dies gilt stellenweise auch für die Rechtschreibung: Da die englische Graphotaktik ein /i/ im Wortauslaut regelmäßig nicht als ⟨i⟩ oder ⟨ie⟩, sondern mit dem Allograph ⟨y⟩ (bzw. bei Einsilbern mit ⟨ee⟩ oder etymologisch bedingt ⟨e⟩) verschriftet, haben wir eine Reihe von (Schein-)Anglizismen wie *Baby* (und *Handy*), deren Plural nicht wie in der Herkunftssprache eine Substitution erfordern (d.h. *baby+s* > *babies*), sondern (wie auch ihr Genitiv) transparent durch einfaches Suffix gebildet werden (*Babys*).

Man könnte das als **orthographische Grundformkonsistenz von Anglizismen** bezeichnen.
Wenn es allerdings um die Schreibung des Kernvokals geht, wird dieses Prinzip offenbar nicht eingehalten!

Die Schreibung vieler englischer Wörter folgt aus historischen Gründen der Sprachentwicklung dem Muster ⟨…C*VC+e⟩, also ein „stummes“ *e* am Ende nach dem eigentlichen Kern und einem (oder manchmal mehreren) Konsonanten dazwischen. Dieses *e* trifft gerade in Verben im Präsens auf die deutschen Flexionsendungen mit unbetontem Schwa-*e*, weswegen anhanddessen kaum entschieden werden kann, ob die infinitive Grundform *to …e* oder der Verbalstamm *…+* importiert wurde. Sobald es allerdings um Flexionsformen geht, deren deutsche Endung kein (optionales) *e* aufweist, gehen die amtlichen Regeln davon aus, dass der deutschen Flexion der englische Stamm zugrundeliegen hätte und nicht die Nennform, weswegen das *e* entfällt, z.B.:

- *to chill* > *chillen*:

  - *ich chille, du chillst, er chillt*
  - *gechillt / *gechilled / ?chilled*
  - kein *e* im Englischen
- *to jog* > *jog**g**en*:

  - *ich jogge, du joggst, sie joggt*
  - *gejoggt / *gejogged*
  - bspw. *Jogger* und *Jogginghose*
  - kein *e* im Englischen
  - Konsonantverdopplung in beiden Sprachen regulär
- *to skate > skaten*:

  - *ich skate, du skatest, sie skatet*
  - *geskatet / *geskated*
  - bspw. *Skater*
  - das *e* der Endung wird immer gesprochen; beachte: *Skat*
- *to like > liken*:

  - *ich like, **du likst** / *likest, **er likt** / *liket*
  - ***gelikt** / *geliket / *geliked*
  - aber „Gib mir ein *Like*!“ – im Substantiv bleibt das *e* unausgesprochen erhalten!
- _to fake > faken:

  - *ich fake, **du fakst** / *fakest, **sie fakt** / *faket*
  - ***gefakt** / *gefaket / *gefaked*
  - aber „Das ist *fake* / ein *Fake*!“ – im Adjektiv und Substantiv bleibt das *e* unausgesprochen erhalten!
  - beachte: *Fakt, fuck*
- *to recycle > recyc**el**n / *recyclen*:

  - *ich recycle / recycel* (je nach Aussprache), *du recycelst / *recyclest, er recycelt / *recyclet*,
  - *recycelt / *recyclet / *recycled*
- *to cancel > canceln*:

  - *ich cancel / canc**le*** (je nach Aussprache), *du cancelst, sie cancelt*,
  - *gecancelt / *gecanceled / *gecancelled / *gecancellt*
  - die Konsonantverdopplung im Partizip wird nicht übernommen
- *woke > woke / *wok*:

  - *woker, am ?woksten / ?wokesten*
  - das *e* in der Grundform bleibt erhalten, obwohl es nicht gesprochen wird, aber wie steht es um den Superlativ?

Gibt es ein orthographisches Grundprinzip, das diese Regelung des wegfallenden *e* erfordert, oder sind die amtlichen Regeln wirklich so inkonsequent wie dargestellt?
(Mit dem Wechsel zwischen *le* und *el* komme ich eher klar.)

Comment: Die (noch nicht veröffentlichten) amtlichen Regeln 2024 werden *gefaked* als Variante zulassen: https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/amtliches-regelwerk-und-woerterverzeichnis-der-deutschensprache-grundlegende-neubearbeitung/

Comment: @DavidVogt Was soll denn aus "gefaked" bei attributivem Gebrauch werden? "Das gefakede Foto" (statt "gefakete")? Ich habe das noch nie gehört. Sagt das irgendjemand so?

Comment: Das e ist zwar "stumm", hat aber trotzdem eine wichtige Funktion. "gefakt" würde ich gefühlt eben genau so aussprechen wie es da steht, also "gefackt", während "gefaket" ja gerade darauf hindeutet, wie man es denn richtig ausspricht. Das gleiche gilt für "like" und "woke". Es geht ja nicht um lecken oder asiatische Bratpfannen. Wenn die Regeln also ein Weglassen des e in diesen wichtigen Fällen vorschreiben, taugen die Regeln nichts.

Comment: @Raketenolli „gefakte Fakten“ wäre nach aktuellem Stand tatsächlich (orthographisch) korrekt.

Comment: Das "amtliche Regelwerk" sucht nicht nach konsisten Regeln, die man auf Fremdwörter anwenden sollte, sondern deduziert die Regeln aus dem empirisch festgestellten Sprachgebrauch. Inkonsistent sind also die Sprecher des Deutschen.

Comment: @userunknown Das mag der Anspruch sein und wäre so auch wünschenswert, aber ich vermute stark, dass in diesem Fall die Festlegung der Verwendung vorausging. In einem Korpus mit nicht redigierten Texten dürften meiner Beobachtung nach die Schreibungen mit _e_ signifikant häufiger sein.

Answer (score 1):

Das »Prinzip« ist es, möglichst bekannten Mustern zu entsprechen, das heißt, sobald es einen deutschen Teil – das ist die Flexion – gibt, muss er zur deutschen Orthographie passen. Formen wie *liket* haben ein Problem: Sie enden offensichtlich in der deutschen Endung "-et", dem majestätisch klingenden Imperativ Plural mit Schwa (Liket mein Video, und abonnieret mich!) und nicht in "-t", denn diese folgt im Deutschen nie auf *e*. Nur die Endung "-t" macht klar, dass kein Schwa enthalten ist.

Das Problem besteht in den "baren" Formen nicht; dort erkennt der Leser das englische Wort, wie in *das Like*. Hier gibt es keinen deutschen Teil. Das gleiche spricht auch für die Partizip II Formen auf *-ed*, wie in *geliked*. Diese haben aber das Problem, dass man diese nicht sinnvoll flektieren kann, deswegen sollte man der Konsistenz halber darauf verzichten.

Wer sich daran stört, dass das *i* in *likt* aussieht, als wäre es kurz, dem
halte ich dagegen, dass Formen wie *trabt*, *legt*, *bebt*, *hupt* auch lang sind, obwohl mehrere Konsonanten auf den Vokal folgen. Es ist also auch nach deutschen Regeln das *i* in *likt* lang. Wäre ist *lick*, wäre es ja auch *lickt*. Das *a* in *gefakt* ist auch so "lang" wie in *gehakt*.

Das Problem, dass hier entsteht, ist hauptsächlich, dass das englische Wort nicht mehr so gut zu erkennen ist. Aber das ist nicht zu umgehen, denn wenn man flektiert, ist das Wort auf jeden Fall verändert. Die Praxis, bei Fremdwörtern mit z.B. Apostrophen Flexion von Fremdwort zu trennen, gibt es im Deutschen nicht.

<sub>Ich persönlich bin dafür, dass "Leik" und "gefejkt" zu schreiben, aber hier wendet sich mein eigenes Prinzip gegen mich: Auch wenn "e"+"j" genau den richtigen Laut produziert, ist "ej" ein Muster, dass im Deutschen nicht auftaucht, es hätte also eher geringe Akzeptanz.</sub>

Comment: Warum nicht «gefekt» – nach demselben Muster wie beim Wort «Keks» (von englisch _cakes_)?

Comment: @mach Weil wir uns dann entscheiden müssten, dass die Diphthonge "ou" und "ej" den deutschen Vokalen "o" und "e" entsprechen. Für mich eindeutig nicht, und ich zucke innerlich immer zusammen, wenn jemand "Code" wie "Kot" ausspricht.

Comment: Nun ja, beim Wort «Keks» tun wir es ja bereits – oder zuckst du dabei auch zusammen? Übrigens ist meine deutsche Aussprache von «Code» [koːd], nicht [koːt].